# MFC Workspace bar

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on a software written by someone other than me. My task was to get rid of the previous library used to create the GUI, which was `Code Jockey`, and to replace it with pure `MFC`. I am using `CFrameWnd` to create my mainframe where I create toolbars etc.

This is the previous library's code snippet creating the workspace bar:

```
if ( !m_tabbarWorkspace.Create(this, ID_VIEW_WORKSPACE,
    _T("Workspace"), CSize(225,100), CBRS_LEFT ))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create dialog bar m_tabbarWorkspace\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

`m_tabbarWorkspace` is an object from a class derived from `CControlBar`. As of now the code is functioning perfectly without a workspace bar. It runs and I can use all of the functionality.

What is a best way to create said bar and insert it into an already existing parent window?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you define your usage of "Workspace bar"?  Do you mean a tool bar or a dialog bar?  Or, perhaps, a CView object?

Comment: I will be using it as a Dock-able window which is tree view compatible. I will be linking it with the CTreeView class, that I know how, but as for your question I am not sure what is the best type of bar to use, that is what I need help with. Which class or which class should I derive from to achieve the desired controls

Comment: That depends on the installed version of Visual Studio. If you have a relatively new one, you can take advantage of the [BCG](http://www.bcgsoft.com/) classes that came as part of the Visual Studio Feature Pack.  Otherwise, you'll need to use the base MFC classes. Something like a [CDialogBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkcfwe6(v=vs.90).aspx) as a parent that contains a child tree control should provide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CDialogBar or a CPaneDialog